# How to Append the value of a variable and not the variable itself

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

So lets say I have

```
a = Some complicated code that changes
list = {}
AppendTo[list, a]
```

Obviously it  would give me

```
list={a, a, a, ...}
```

Due to symbolic nature of mathematica when I change `a` all of the elements will change.I want to append only the current value of `a` so that i can add different values in `list`.

Comment: "Due to symbolic nature of mathematica when I change `a` all of the elements will change." No, they won't, unless the "element" in `a` changes. Please show us a specific example that can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
a := 5 x
list = {}

x = 1

b = a

AppendTo[list, b]
(*{5}*)

x = 2

b = a

AppendTo[list, b]
(*{5, 10}*)
```